# Combining blobs from PDO query result

Tags: php, oracle, pdo

I have a table which I'll call `table_x` holding file attachments as binary large objects in an Oracle database.

However, it does not have one row per file, it has one row per 28kb chunk of a file. Each blob is never more than 28kb.

Rows might look like:

```
attachsysfilename        file_seq      file_size      file_data
blah.xlsx                0             12000          <BLOB>
poo.xlsx                 0             28000          <BLOB>
poo.xlsx                 1             9000           <BLOB>
```

No row has a file size > 28000 bytes. Each `attachsysfilename` and `file_seq` combination is unique. When a file is above 28000 bytes, it is split across 2+ rows depending on how many 28kb chunks are needed to store the file.

If I directly export the blobs from the database, I need to concatenate blobs that are stored on 2+ rows before opening them. For example if I had a 2 part Excel file downloaded, I'd have to combine the parts, if using Windows, like `type part1.xlsx part2.xlsx > combined.xlsx` on the command line. The combined file would open properly, but opening either part individually would return an error.

I am writing some pages in PHP that access this data using PDO and would like to use PHP to similarly concatenate 2+ blobs when they represent the same file.

I have no problem writing a page to download files that are stored on only one row (28kb or less in size). I have that working as follows:

```
$att = $cono -> prepare (" SELECT attachsysfilename,
                                  file_size,
                                  file_data
                           from   table_x
                           where  attachsysfilename = :file_id
                          ");

$att -> bindParam(':file_id', $file_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$att -> execute();
$att -> bindColumn(1, $attachsysfilename, PDO::PARAM_STR, 256);
$att -> bindColumn(2, $file_size, PDO::PARAM_STR, 256);
$att -> bindColumn(3, $file_data, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
$att_row = $att -> fetch( PDO::FETCH_BOUND );

header("Content-type: application/vnd.openxmlfo");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename = $attachsysfilename");
fpassthru($file_data);
```

The above works fine whenever the file is limited to 1 row of the table.

This is my best attempt at handling those files on 2+ rows:

```
$att = $cono -> prepare (" SELECT attachsysfilename,
                                  file_size,
                                  file_data
                           from   table_x
                           where  attachsysfilename = :file_id
                          ");

$att -> bindParam(':file_id', $file_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$att -> execute();
$att -> bindColumn(1, $attachsysfilename, PDO::PARAM_STR, 256);
$att -> bindColumn(2, $file_size, PDO::PARAM_STR, 256);
$att -> bindColumn(3, $file_data, PDO::PARAM_LOB);

$combined_blob = '';

while (  $att_row = $att -> fetch( PDO::FETCH_BOUND ) )
{ 
  $combined_blob = $combined_blob . $file_data;

}

header("Content-type: application/vnd.openxmlfo");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename = $attachsysfilename");
fpassthru($combined_blob);
?>
```

Which returns this error (in the downloaded files):

```
<b>Warning</b>:  fpassthru() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in ....
```

The goal is to combine the 2+ blobs in php so that the combined blob can be downloaded as a file, not any one part.

Comment: RTFM: [fpassthru](http://php.net/fpassthru). it expects a FILE HANDLE as its argument. You're stuffing in a string. Why can't you just `echo $combined_blob`?

Comment: If I echo it then it shows a string, so files I download look like `Resource id #2` (just that text, no binary data). A var_dump also shows it to be of a string type. I suspect this happens when I set $combined_blob initially to a blank space.

Comment: @PatrickQ I am not merging independent files like PDFs where I want pages from one added to another. These are single files that were uploaded and then split evenly into chunks at the binary level. As in my example, the files are valid if simply concatenated using `type` on the Windows command line (equivalent of `cat` in linux?)

Comment: fpassthru is for reading a file from disk, via a previous fopen()'d file handle, and sending to the client. You have no on-disk file. you have only the blobs you fetched from the db, which arrive as strings. you build a bigger string from those smaller ones, and then ALL you have to do is echo out that string. if you get `Resource`, then something is very wrong.

Comment: fpassthru does work when the blob is the blob from just one row of the table (first example provided). There are examples of others using fpassthru with blobs retrieved using PDO. Example https://jeremycook.ca/2010/02/21/handling-binary-data-with-pdo/

Comment: @MarcB your point about the strings was helpful though, I just solved it by changing `$att -> bindColumn(3, $file_data, PDO::PARAM_LOB);` to `$att -> bindColumn(3, $file_data, PDO::PARAM_STR, 28000);` and then doing as you suggested (echoing the combined string). By having binded the column as PARAM_LOB the value was no longer a string (I think). If you want to point this out as the answer I'll go ahead and give you credit. Thanks.

Comment: ah yeah. totally forgot about blobs being fetched as resources... I rarely ever have 'em in the stuff I work on.